# using mysql system user

Tags: mysql, redhat, rhel

What are the possible disadvantages / pitfalls of using linux system user 'mysql' to work with mysql server instead of creating a separate use?

Comment: You can't do configuration file settings and start / stop mysql server with that. Any thing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do configuration file settings and start / stop mysql server with that. Got it.